# What Visual Studio do I need for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, visual-studio

I am in the process of installing MySQL on Windows and it asks for Visual Studio   in the check requirements part. I didn't had Visual Studio installed before, so I download and installed the Visual Studio Community. Then I clicked on the MySQL check button to see if Visual Studio was installed and I does not recognize it. (I also tried to close MySQL installation and open it again, and also restart my computer)

Do I need a specific version of Visual Studio?

Thanks, 
André.

Comment: What does Visual Studio have to do with MySQL?

Comment: I've no idea @David , never used MySQL, but I'm sure it asks for it in the check requirements part. I would like to post a print of it but I'm so miserable that I don't even have enough badges to do it :(

Comment: HI @David, here you can see that Visual Studio can be used fo MySQL http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/visualstudio/

Answer (score 34):

You do not need Visual Studio for MySQL.

However, if you would like to use "MySQL for Visual Studio", it will require VS 2008, 2010, 2012, 2013, 2015, or newer versions as time goes on (per installer).

When installing using the Windows MSI installer, in Setup Type, you probably selected Developer Default, which includes "MySQL for Visual Studio", which will require Visual Studio.  Choose a Setup Type that does not install "MySQL for Visual Studio" if you do not need VS.

Comment: When installing, choose Setup Type "Custom" then keep everything but remove "MySql for Visual Studio" to the left side by clicking the left arrow. That's it!

Answer (score 3):

If you are installing MySQL on Windows, It requires Visual studio to be installed on your system. At the time of answering this question, supported versions are visual studio 2012, 2013, 2015 or 2017.

please install .Net developer tools for Visual studio if MySQL setup is not recognizing your visual studio. It will work. Same worked for me.

Comment: This answer is outdated, and does not provide any source.

Comment: Answer is not outdated... Current Installation bugs out on a lot of systems, requiring the .net dev tools for visual studio as a workaround for some, not all...
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85908

Answer (score 0):

The [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-installer.html) of the installer reads:

> ## Installation Requirements
>
> MySQL Installer requires Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 or later. If this version is not installed on the host computer, you can download it by visiting the Microsoft website.

So, nothing about Visual Studio.

But, when trying to install the MySQL Shell, you can get the error message:

> MySQL Shell 8.0.19 2…
>   This application requires Visual Studio 2019 Redistributable. Please install the Redistributable then run this installer again.

You will probably see the same requirements for "MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.9 2"

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version you have installed. For example, installing mysql8.0 on windows requires the operating system to have Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 installed in advance.

Microsoft official website https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0 , just download the corresponding environment.

Answer (score -1):

MySQL for Visual Studio can only integrate directly into Visual Studio 2008, 2010, and 2012.

Comment: This answer is outdated, and provided without source.