# How to install MySQL in Windows OS?

Tags: python, mysql-python

I've just recently downloaded MySQL Community Server software and started to install it on my laptop. However, I currently have two alert messages pop up:

1) Some products have conflicts i.e 'the selected path already exists'. What should I do for this alert message? Should I store the MySQL software in some other file?

2) During the 'Checking Requirements' stage, it's asking me for two product requirements of which I need to install prior to MySQL. The product requirements were MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.8 and Python 3.7 (64-bit). Is it necessary to install Visual Studio in order to go ahead with the MySQL installation process? Also, I already downloaded Python 3.7 but it's a 32-bit version. MySQL is demanding for a 64-bit Python version. What should I do? Should I uninstall my current Python software and download a 64-bit software? The thing is, I don't know if 64 bit is available and am actually new to this. I would really appreciate the help.

My friend told me to go 'dual mode' i.e to install Linux in my laptop but I feel that's risky. Any thoughts?

I've tried re-installing Python again but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I think it's best to install MySQL using default configs unless you know exactly what you're doing. If it says path already exists perhaps you installed the software before but didn't fully uninstall it? It wouldn't hurt to check the path to see what's in there and if it is nothing important just clear it and continue with the installation. Also there is a [64-bit python](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. And what about Visual Studio? It says I need to install version 2012, 2013, 2015 or 2017 version as well but I don't want to add more space to my laptop. I already have Sublime Text installed. What should I do?

Comment: I don't think you need Visual Studio. You should check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32285120/what-visual-studio-do-i-need-for-mysql)